# Difference between "already know" and "have already known"

Tags: word-usage, tenses, writing-style

I've been thinking that the phrase "**already know**" is different from the phrase "**have already known**".

- **Already know**: I know something clearly at this point of saying (present)
- **Have already known**: I've known something so far. (present perfect)

I may be confused in the explanation.

I don't know when we can use each of these phrases properly.

Thanks and best regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Present perfect for past action with present effect](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57869/present-perfect-for-past-action-with-present-effect). As Quasiperfect says, the word *already* is irrelevant, so this question is simply about how/when to use present perfect.

Answer (score 11):

When we use the word *already* with the present perfect, we are usually referring to a completed action (which has present relevance):

- I have already cooked dinner.
- She has gone already.

But *knowing* cannot be regarded as a completed action in the same sense. It denotes a present or past state. So you cannot say:

- I have already known that they are getting married.
- I have already known how to speak Russian.

What you can say of course is:

- I have already heard that they are getting married.
- I have already learned how to speak Russian.

because *hearing* and *learning* can be regarded as completable actions.

And you can use *already* with the past simple to denote a state of knowledge that existed at some point in the past (and may or may not exist in the present):

- I already knew that they were getting married (before I read it in the newspaper).
- I already knew how to speak Russian (so I didn't need to do the course).

---

Unlike some languages English does not have two verbs to distinguish between a. knowing a person and b. knowing a fact or how to do something. With the former meaning it would be possible to say:

- I have already known many people like you and have learned not to trust them.

Answer (score 0):

Already is just a modifier emphasizing that it has already happened. The difference is between the present (*I know*) and the present perfect (*I have known*).

You would use the present tense when confronted with the something you've encounter beforehand.

> I already know how to turn on the television.
>
> I know how to drive a car.

You would use the present perfect to express something that happened previously, without specifying the time. You'll only use the present perfect and "already" when expressing previous events relative to the present.

> I have been to France before.
>
> I have already known many people before meeting you.

The past perfect is used to express something that happened before something else, without specifying the time.

> I had gone to France before I went to Germany.
>
> I had already known the story before I saw the film.

Comment: I know how to you these tenses basically but I kinda feel my two examples seem to be as the same meaning. Thank Quasiperfect much.

Comment: It's to do with whether and when you're comparing them. They could, logically, represent the same thing in different forms.