# Grammar about haven't and didn't

Tags: grammar

> I haven't took your class for a long time.
>   I didn't take your class for a long time.

Which one is more appropriate?

Comment: Neither: "I haven't taken. . . "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I didn't phone Peter this morning / I haven't phoned Peter this morning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/303644/i-didnt-phone-peter-this-morning-i-havent-phoned-peter-this-morning) (itself closed as a duplicate; there are other questions addressing this issue).

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer – I am a newcomer to this site, but I have more than 20 years' experience as a book editor.

Your first sentence, I think, expresses your intended meaning more clearly than the second, but you need to replace *took* with *taken*, which is the past participle of the verb *to take*. **I haven't *taken* your class for a long time.** So it's something you have done, but it's in the past.

The second sentence is grammatically correct, but its meaning is different.    It almost needs an explanation.  For example, *I didn't take your class for a long time because it was held at a time that did not suit me*.

Comment: Nicely answered, and welcome to EL&U.

Comment: 'Haven't taken' is a continuous usage here, implying that the (negative) state continues till now. 'Didn't take' implies an endpoint (at least in notional terms: 'I didn't take driving lessons in January. Or February.') to the negative state.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, thank you for clarifying that. It's what I was trying to get at but I couldn't think how to explain it.