# “you checked” or “you have checked”

Tags: word-choice, grammar, present-perfect, simple-past

```
/**
 * @returns {string} The type of the variable that you checked/have checked.
 */
function check($var) {

}
```

Should I use *checked* or *have checked* in the above comment? Why?

Note: I don’t know why it’s so hard for me to understand the *past simple* and *present perfect*.

Comment: Related question, [Present perfect for past action with present effect](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57869/present-perfect-for-past-action-with-present-effect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both refer to a past activity but, the simple past needs a time expression that fixes the action at a certain past moment,(yesterday,...ago, last... or a previous verb in past), whereas the present perfect does not mention  exactly when and may have  a present consequence or effect. Since one can not see what was written before (if there was a verb in Past), I consider the Present Perfect the correct tense in this case.