# "something we missed" vs. "something we have missed"

Tags: differences, past-tense, present-perfect, relative-clauses

I was wondering when to use 'have' in a sentence like 'There has to be something we (have) missed'. I've looked only, but couldn't find a clear-cut answer.

A clear explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question is too broad. If you Google "present perfect (tense)", you will get millions of examples.

Comment: Related question. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57869/present-perfect-for-past-action-with-present-effect. You can [search here](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=past+simple+present+perfect), too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Have* is the marker for the present perfect tense, and as its name implies, it talks about completed past acton (that's the *perfect* part of the name) in the interval from some time in the past right up to the *present* or affecting the *present*.  The past participle alone (here, *missed*) gives the simple past tense, which talks about past action without reference to the present. If your sentence severs the connection to the present, don't use the present perfect:

> *We **have found** the answer last Saturday.

Likewise, if your sentence explicitly mentions the present, don't use the past tense:

> *We **found** the answer by now.

If the present is neither excluded nor included, as in your sentence, then either tense is acceptable.